is time.Tick cause memory leak since you can't close the channel explicitly because it's receive-only channel in Go? Does return statement solve it
Let's say I have a function as follows:
func fetchData() {
    interval := time.Minutes * 15
    ticker := time.Tick(interval)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker:
            fetchSomething()
        case <-stopFetching:
            return
        }
    }
}

And let's say this function is invoked as follows:
go fetchData()

Imagine that stopFetching is just a channel when it's triggered return statement will execute.
In this case, will there be any memory leak regarding ticker here? Becasue it cannot be closed with close(ticker) since it's receive-only channel. How to handle this gracefully. When I wrote the code static-checker warned me by saying using time.Tick leaks the underlying ticker, consider using it only in endless functions, tests and the main package, and use time.NewTicker here (SA1015)
I'm not sure what to do here..

Yes, there will be a leak. Quoting from time.Tick():

Tick is a convenience wrapper for NewTicker providing access to the ticking channel only. While Tick is useful for clients that have no need to shut down the Ticker, be aware that without a way to shut it down the underlying Ticker cannot be recovered by the garbage collector; it "leaks". Unlike NewTicker, Tick will return nil if d <= 0.

The doc says that it's useful when you do not want to (do not have to) shut down the Ticker. Since you do want to shut it down, don't use time.Tick().
Note that the leak does not come from you not closing the channel (a non-closed channel is no different than any other Go value in this regard), the leak comes from time.Tick() using internal resources for the timing (which may be a goroutine and/or other system resources).
Instead use time.NewTicker(), of which you may call the Ticker.Stop() method to free associated resources.
For example:
func fetchData() {
    interval := time.Minute * 15
    ticker := time.NewTicker(interval)
    defer ticker.Stop()

    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            fetchSomething()
        case <-stopFetching:
            return
        }
    }
}

Here's how you can test it (by changing interval to 1 second):
func main() {
    time.AfterFunc(time.Second*10, func() {
        close(stopFetching)
    })
    fetchData()
}

func fetchSomething() {
    fmt.Println("Fetching something")
}

This will output Fetching something 10 times then stop. Try it on the Go Playground.

Thanks for the answer, I'm thing what kind of a procedure could be applicable for time.Tick then?

when I use ticker.Stop(), I checked the documentation and it says // Stop does not close the channel, to prevent a concurrent goroutine  reading from the channel from seeing an erroneous "tick". Isn't it also concerning that channel won't be closed even though no more ticks will be sent? Seems like it's also causing a memory leak.

A channel does not need to be closed from a GC perspective. Once the channel (or ticker that owns the channel in this case) goes out of scope, it will be GC'ed.

@baris I've written this in my answer too, but I repeat: not closing a channel does not leak resources. Other things that a ticker uses may leak resources unless you call Ticker.Stop().
